# Disable Tomcat default servlet

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I am using Tomcat server to run my application deployed as WAR. The application does not serve static content or JSPs. Is there a way to disable the default servlet and the jsp servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but it should be sufficient to disable all connectors: Edit `conf/server.xml` and remove all `<Connector>` entries (there should be one active HTML connector by default). Restart and check if the server still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Servlet containers are often shipped with a default servlet. Tomcat also [has one](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/default-servlet.html). You can disable it by deleting the entries in `conf/web.xml` that are associated with `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>`. Remove both the `<servlet>` entry and the associated `<servlet-mapping>` entry.
The same can be done for `<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>`.

But this solution is container dependent. So if you ship the webapp to a different container, and you forget to remove the default servlet, then the behavior of your app differs a bit.

A solution that is container independent is to create your own default servlet, thereby overruling the default one provided by the container (such at Tomcat). You can do so by creating a servlet with the behavior that you want, and mapping it to `"/"`.

For example:

```
public class MyDefaultServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(404);
    }
}
```

It should always throws a HTTP 404 (`NOT FOUND`) when accessed, otherwise it will return a HTTP 200 (`OK`) on every undefined URL request.

And in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myDefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>example.demo.MyDefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myDefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```